# PHP - Cookie expira após 48h

Tags: php

Boa tarde,

Estou tendo um problema ao usar Cookies no PHP, estou usando dois cookies, um que define o usuário e outro que define a linguagem utilizada, no entanto, desde que comecei a usar o segundo cookie, ambos os cookies estão finalizando após 48h, mesmo setando períodos maiores (30d-365d).

Segue um exemplo do código:

```
setcookie("id_usuario", $id_usuario, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
setcookie("lang", "$lang", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

Alguém tem ideia do motivo dos cookies estarem limpando em 48h e/ou uma forma melhor de manter mais de um cookie por longos períodos? meus usuários estão reclamando muito de ter que relogar a cada 2 dias.

Agradeço.

Comment: Basicamente é falta de entendimento das sessões do PHP. O Cookie é só um "portador" da identificação, só mudar o tempo de vida dele não vai ajudar. Precisa aumentar o tempo da sessão toda (incluindo o arquivo que é gerado). Tem que tomar cuidado pra não encher o servidor de sessão aberta à toa, nesse caso (por exemplo, desabilitando completamente o tempo de sessão, coisa que já vi gente fazendo).

Comment: Veja um dos fatores que é fundamental ajustar: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime - sem isso, o cookie pode durar pra sempre, mas na hora que for feito o acesso ele não vai servir para nada, pois a sessão já terá sido deletada.